# Reset form and validation

Tags: forms, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a problem with a dialog modal who don,t want to close even with a function

I have this code to reset and close the modal, the resetting is ok but nothing close with cancel, I use the resetForm() function
I have a form with this structure ( form and rules )

```
<template>
    <div class="text-center">
        <v-dialog
                v-model="dialog"
        >
            <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
                <v-btn class="addGroup" v-on="on">Add a group</v-btn>
            </template>
            <v-form
                    ref="form"
                    v-model="valid"
                    lazy-validation
            >

            <v-card>
                <v-card-title
                        class="headline grey lighten-2"
                        primary-title
                >
                    Add a group
                </v-card-title>

                    <v-stepper v-model="e1">
                        <v-stepper-header class="stepHeader">
                            <v-stepper-step :complete="e1 > 1" step="1">Choose a name</v-stepper-step>

                            <v-divider></v-divider>

                            <v-stepper-step :complete="e1 > 2" step="2">Select fixtures</v-stepper-step>

                            <v-divider></v-divider>

                            <v-stepper-step :complete="e1 > 3" step="3">Apply a recipe</v-stepper-step>

                            <v-divider></v-divider>

                            <v-stepper-step :complete="e1 > 4" step="4" >Select dates</v-stepper-step>

                            <v-divider></v-divider>

                            <v-stepper-step step="5">Summary</v-stepper-step>
                        </v-stepper-header>

                        <v-stepper-items>
                            <v-stepper-content  step="1" class="mt-6">
                                <v-card
                                >
                                    <div class="step chooseName">
                                        <h3>Create a group</h3>

                                        <p class="mt-12">Choose a name for your group</p>
                                        <v-text-field
                                                :rules="rules.name"
                                                @keyup.enter="e1 = 2"
                                                v-model="form.groupName"
                                        ></v-text-field>


                                    </div>
                                </v-card>

                                <v-btn
                                        color="primary"
                                        @click="e1 = 2"
                                >
                                    Continue
                                </v-btn>

                                <v-btn
                                        text
                                        @click="dialog = !dialog"
                                >
                                    Cancel</v-btn>
                            </v-stepper-content>

                            <v-stepper-content step="2" class="mt-6">
                                <v-card
                                >
                                    <div class="step selectFixtures">
                                        <h3><v-icon @click="e1 = 1">mdi-chevron-left</v-icon>Select fixtures</h3>

                                        <p class="mt-12 mb-6"

                                        >Choose fixtures you want associate with {{form.groupName}}.</p>
                                        <v-select
                                                :rules="rules.fixture"
                                                v-model="form.selectedFixture"
                                                :items="fixtures"
                                                item-text="name"
                                        ></v-select>
                                    </div>
                                </v-card>

                                <v-btn
                                        color="primary"
                                        @click="e1 = 3"
                                >
                                    Continue
                                </v-btn>

                                <v-btn
                                        text
                                        @click="dialog = !dialog"
                                >
                                    Cancel</v-btn>
                            </v-stepper-content>
                            <v-stepper-content step="3" class="mt-6">
                                <v-card
                                        flat
                                        height="68vh"
                                        rounded
                                >

                                    <div class="step applyRecipe">
                                        <h3><v-icon @click="e1 = 2">mdi-chevron-left</v-icon>Apply a recipe to your group</h3>

                                        <p class="mt-12 mb-6">Select a recipe for the group {{groupName}}.</p>
                                        <div class="selectRecipe">
                                            <v-select
                                                    class="mr-6"

                                                    v-model="form.selectedRecipe"
                                                    :items="recipe"
                                                    item-text="name"
                                                    item-value="duration"
                                                    return-object>
                                            </v-select>
                                            <p>or</p>
                                            <create_recipe></create_recipe>
                                        </div>


                                    </div>
                                </v-card>
                                <v-btn
                                        color="primary"
                                        @click="e1 = 4"

                                >
                                    Continue
                                </v-btn>

                                <v-btn
                                        text
                                        @click="dialog = !dialog"
                                >
                                    Cancel</v-btn>
                            </v-stepper-content>

                            <v-stepper-content step="4" class="mt-6">
                                <v-card
                                >
                                    <div class="selectDates">
                                        <h3><v-icon @click="e1 = 3">mdi-chevron-left</v-icon>Select start date</h3>

                                        <p class="mt-6">Select the launch date of the Tuscan sun recipe for the {{groupName}} group</p>
                                        <p>The end date will be set automatically according to the parameters of your recipe</p>
                                        <v-date-picker
                                                class="mt-6 ml-6"
                                                v-model="selectedDate"
                                                no-title
                                                :date-format="date => new Date(date).toDateString()"
                                        >
                                        </v-date-picker>
                                    </div>
                                </v-card>

                                <v-btn
                                        color="primary"
                                        @click="e1 = 5"

                                >
                                    Continue
                                </v-btn>

                                <v-btn
                                        text
                                        @click="dialog = !dialog"
                                >
                                    Cancel</v-btn>
                            </v-stepper-content>

                            <v-stepper-content step="5" class="mt-6">
                                <v-card
                                >
                                    <div class="stepChooseName">
                                        <h3><v-icon @click="e1 = 4">mdi-chevron-left</v-icon>Summary</h3>

                                        <p class="answer">Group name :</p>
                                        <p class="subtitle">{{form.groupName}}</p>
                                        <v-divider></v-divider>

                                    </div>
                                </v-card>

                                <v-btn
                                        @click="submit()"
                                >
                                    Add group
                                </v-btn>

                                <v-btn
                                        text
                                        @click="dialog = !dialog"
                                >
                                    Cancel</v-btn>
                            </v-stepper-content>
                        </v-stepper-items>
                    </v-stepper>
            </v-card>
            </v-form>
        </v-dialog>
    </div>
</template>
```

I have this code to reset and close the modal, the resetting is ok but nothing close with cancel, I use the resetForm() function
I have a form with this structure ( form and rules )

````
<script>

    import Create_recipe from "./create_recipe";
    export default {
        components: {Create_recipe},
        props: ['groups', 'fixtures'],
        groups: [],
        data() {
            const defaultForm = Object.freeze({
                groupName: '',
                selectedFixture: [],
                selectedRecipe: '',
                selectedScenario: '',
            });
            return {
                form: Object.assign({}, defaultForm),
                valid: true,
                rules: {
                    name: [val => (val || '').length > 0 || 'This field is required'],
                    fixture: [val => (val || '').length > 0 || 'fixture is required'],
                    recipe: [val => (val || '').length > 0 || 'recipe is required'],
                },
                dialog: null,
                defaultForm,
                e1:0,
                counterOfUnnamed:'',
                checkbox: true,
                fixtures: this.fixtures,
                selectedDate: new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10),

                recipe: [{
                        id:1,
                        name: 'Tuscan sun',
                        duration: '5',
                    },
                    {   id:2,
                        name: 'Montreal summer',
                        duration: '10',
                    },
                    {   id:3,
                        name: 'French spring',
                        duration: '365',
                    }
                ],
            }
        },
        methods: {
            numberOfFixture() {
                return this.form.selectedFixture.length;
                },
            resetForm () {
                this.$refs.form.reset();
                this.dialog = false
            },
            submit() {
                if (!this.form.groupName) {
                    this.form.groupName = "Unnamed" + this.counterOfUnnamed;
                    this.counterOfUnnamed = this.counterOfUnnamed + 1;
                    this.counterOfUnnamed = parseInt(this.counterOfUnnamed);
                }
                var self = this;
                http.post('group/create', {
                    name: self.form.groupName,
                }).then((result) => {
                    self.groups.push(result);
                    self.resetForm();
                })


            },

            },
        computed: {
            displayFixturesName() {
                return this.form.selectedFixture.join(', ');
                },

            formIsValid() {
                return (
                    this.form.selectedFixture &&
                    this.form.selectedRecipe
                )
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

But when I launch the reset function, the form is reset but the validation appears.

How can I solve it ?
````

Comment: Is it possible to create a codepen  with the minimal reproduction input fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case use this.$refs.form.resetValidation() for reset the validation after reset

```
resetForm () {
  this.$refs.form.reset()
  this.$refs.form.resetValidation()
},
```

Here is the working code

Codepen link: https://codepen.io/chansv/pen/QWWExBz?editors=1010

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-form
      ref="form"
      v-model="valid"
    >
      <v-text-field
        v-model="formObj.name"
        :counter="10"
        :rules="nameRules"
        label="Name"
        required
      ></v-text-field>

      <v-text-field
        v-model="formObj.email"
        :rules="emailRules"
        label="E-mail"
        required
      ></v-text-field>



      <v-btn
        :disabled="!valid"
        color="success"
        class="mr-4"
        @click="submitForm"
      >
        Submit
      </v-btn>

      <v-btn
        color="error"
        class="mr-4"
        @click="reset"
      >
        Reset Form
      </v-btn>

    </v-form>
  </v-app>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    const defaultForm = Object.freeze({
      name: '',
      email: '',
    })
  return {
    formObj: Object.assign({}, defaultForm),
    valid: true,
    nameRules: [
      v => !!v || 'Name is required',
      v => (v && v.length <= 10) || 'Name must be less than 10 characters',
    ],
    emailRules: [
      v => !!v || 'E-mail is required',
      v => /.+@.+\..+/.test(v) || 'E-mail must be valid',
    ],

  };
},

  methods: {
    submitForm () {
      console.log(this.formObj);
    },
    reset () {
      this.$refs.form.reset();
      console.log(this.formObj);
    },
  },
})
```

If you are reseting the form , no need to set default `value this.form = Object.assign({}, this.defaultForm)`
This reset function automatically resets all the value in the form this.$refs.form.reset()

Comment: Do you know how can I close the modal and at the same time reset form when I click on Cancel Button ?

Comment: Yes add this button inside your modal dialog <v-btn @click="dialog = !dialog">close</v-btn>

Comment: it's just closing dialog but not reseting

Comment: In the cancel button click add @click="resetForm()" and in resetForm function add this line of code      this.dialog = !this.dialog

Comment: I try to make a codepen, but it's so painful to me to make it , I got a lot of code

Comment: I don't put the code at the right place , it's another post

Comment: Yes I know that